# Firebase limit user write access

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

i setup rules to limit user access like this:

```
.write": "auth != null && !root.child('blockedUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)",
```

The problem is, i dont know how to use it on the client side. I am assuming this is duplicate question, but i cant find anything on actual usage of the limited user access.

When user tries to create comment for example, i get an error that permission is denied. Thats desired result, problem is how do i check for the user write permission on the client ?

I was hoping for something like user.canWrite or something along those lines. All i am doing right now is just check if user was authenticated, which he was and there is no mention of read/write access rules in the user object as far as i can tell.

```
 if (this.props.user) {
     firebase.database().ref(`comments/${key}/rating`)
     .transaction(
         (value) => (value += rateValue)
     )}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

By writing you rule you are setting an authorization to authenticated users to write to the specific node of your database.

Therefore, in the client, **you only need to insure that your user is authenticated**. This should be done through Firebase Authentication. See the doc for the web here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

In case the user cannot write to this specific node (either because he/she is not authenticated or because his/her `uid` is listed under the `blockedUsers`) he/she will receive an error in the front-end.

---

*Update following our comments below:*

If you want to be able "to modify the client UI based on the user's role or access level" you should use another mechanism for setting up the authorization: **Custom Claims**. See the doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims.

In this case, in the security rule, you would not check if there is a record under the 'blockedUsers' node but you would check the Claims attached to the token, as explained in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, with my rule i am trying to make sure that user is not blocked/banned if he wants to write to the database. If he is, block him from writing to database. So user can authenticate, but he is not able to write anywhere. So what you are saying is, in this case, i will always get errors, there is no way to check for his writing permission beforehand ? There is no flag or anything on the user ?

Comment: No, there is no flag in the frontend: the rules are enforced (and defined) in the backend, hence the need to call the backend to know if the user can or cannot write to the specific node in the db.

Comment: ok, is there any way to make a call to the database and find out that user does not have the permission ? I could then store it on the client side i guess. I could theoretically just fake some call to db and see if i get this permission denied error, but that seems like ugly hack.
 I need to know that beforehand, because i am doing some local visual stuff before i actualy call the database ( like changing icons when user rates something etc ). This way i cant block that functionality.

Comment: With the authorization defined through some security rules as you have done I don't think there is a way to know without trying to write. However, there is another way to control access and set up some authorization: **Custom Claims**. See  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claimsrule. The advantage is that you can access these claims **in the client** and then be able "to modify the client UI based on the user's role or access level".

Comment: @CosmicSeizure Hi, did you have time to look at the possibilities offered by CustomClaims, as detailed above and in the update to the answer?

Comment: Hi, i looked into it, but i ended up using regular authentication and rather improving my backend security instead of spending too much time obsessing if some button is shown or not. If someone wants to hack it localy to show button, they can probably do it anyway.